# First start of TensorFlow. Imports in pywrap_tensorflow.py don't work

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed TensorFlow successfully, but when I've tried to run the example test code from tensorflow.org:

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

I've got the following error message:

```
> ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
> line 58, in <module>
>     from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
> line 28, in <module>
>     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
> line 24, in swig_import_helper
>     _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242,
> in load_module
>     return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>     return _load(spec) ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow can't find your CUDA 9.0 directory. My guess is you accidentally installed tensorflow-gpu instead of tensorflow for cpu. See the
[installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#determine_which_tensorflow_to_install) for more info.

In case you have gpu(s) available, you either installed too new tf version for your CUDA (since v1.6 you need CUDA 9), or you forgot to update `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable so that the cuda path is visible to tensoflow.

Comment: Thank you! I've installed the CPU version and everything works correctly now.